# Browse and Iterate json files in Terrraform and pass variables to module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

For certification purposes I have built a simple AWS policy module based on resource `aws_iam_policy`.

What I am trying to achieve is to put the configuration in a json file, including the policy itself. This is the structure I am using, where the json policy itself is stored in `policy`:

```
{
    "name": "my_test_policy",
    "path": "/",
    "description": "My test policy",
    "policy": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "thesid",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [....],
                "Resource": [....]
            }
        ]
     }
}
```

This is how I am calling the module, it works but I am not happy as I feel there's some area of improvement.

```
module "aws-custom-policy" {
  source = "./modules/aws-custom-policy"
  for_each = fileset("config/policies/", "*.json")
  
  name = jsondecode(file("config/policies/${each.value}")).name
  policy = jsondecode(file("config/policies/${each.value}")).policy
  description = jsondecode(file("config/policies/${each.value}")).description
}
```

This is the module:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name        = var.name
  description = var.description
  policy = jsonencode(var.policy)
}

variable "name" {
  description = "Policy Name"
  type = string
}

variable "description" {
  description = "Policy Description"
  type = string
}

variable "policy" {
  description = "Policy definition"
  type = any
}
```

What I would like to achieve:

1. Parse file once, instead of multiple decoding
2. I would like to avoid passing the whole JSON to the module and let the module retrieves each variables
3. I am not happy with `policy` variable, the `any` type seems somehow wrong

Comment: I think you can pass the JSON file as is. Have you tried that maybe? Minus the name and the description of course, that would have to stay as separate variables.